# Would HDMI Splitter work with Softxpand or Userful setup

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, hdmi, multiple-users, splitter

Trying to setup a multi-user system at my school (1 desktop with 6 users). Just wondering if I could avoid additional vga/hdmi graphics cards in the host computer and use an HDMI splitter like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BTC5S6O) to allow for each screen to be duplicated by the host monitor:

[image]
 Then I would install the version of Softxpand that allows for 6 users to share the single host computer. I don't need to configure sound for more than one user. If it doesn't work with Softxpand would it work with Userful on Ubuntu?

Comment: No. This simply shows the same thing from the one HDMI output to any of the displays connected. It does not allow discrete sessions and output to each display.

Answer (score 0):

*Converting my comment to an answer. However, this question is hardware shopping and ought to be closed.*

**Answer:**
No. This device simply shows the same thing from the one HDMI output to any of the displays connected (duplicates). It does not allow discrete sessions and unique output to each display.